# Tomcat 7 Error, java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed

Tags: 64-bit, tomcat7, java-7, spring-roo

I'm struggling with this error since last week, which occurs on my Win-7 64-bit laptop, but same appliation runs perfectly on a Win-7 32-bit desktop.

I follow the same steps on both the machine:

- In roo shall; script --file $ROO_HOME\samples\pizzashop.roo
- And then 'perform package' and deploy the war file on `tomcat 7`

Environments all 64-bits: `JDK 1.7`, `Spring Roo 1.2.4`, `Tomcat 7.0.47`, (I get same error in Tomcat 6, vm-server also)

Here is the Error stack trace, when I assess any of the pizzashop sample application pages. `Example:  http://localhost:8080/pizzashop/bases?page=1&amp;size=10`

And the request is redirected to `Internal Error` page.

First Error:

```
Oct 28, 2013 12:36:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [pizzashop] in context with path [/pizzashop] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx'.] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jspx$Helper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:537)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
```

Second Error:

```
Oct 28, 2013 1:38:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [pizzashop] in context with path [/pizzashop] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx'.] with root cause
java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:578)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:655)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2538)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1251)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:673)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:229)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:234)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Can someone please help me how to fix the error?

I tried reinstalling spring sts, tomcat, even jdk, but nothing worked.

Comment: I just ran the same war file on tomcat server on my 32-bit windows machine, which ran like without any error. But the issue still persists with my laptop which is 64-bit windows, as all of the servers (both tomcat / vmserver) are throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be different reason for this error. I followed these and it worked for me
1. Start Tomcat as an administrator.
2. Clean Tomcat work directory. Right Click on Server in Eclipse Server view.
3. Give full control to tomcat folde